# Create field of predefined type with string and value, java

Tags: java

I want to be able to write a method with a string and integer as the parameters for example, and I want to then create a variable inside that class with the integer value in which I can later recall. For example:

```
public void setInt(String identifier, Integer) {

}
```

if I then call

```
setInt("age", 25); //stores 25 with identifier "age"
```

it would create a variable called age, which I could later access by calling

```
getInt("age") //would return 25
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Take a look at [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)s. it will not create a variable, but will give you the desired functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hold a `Map` data member, and use it to store values:

```
public class SomeClass {
    // could (should?) be initialized in the ctor
    private Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void setInt (String identifier, int value) {
        // This assumes identifier != null, for clarity
        map.put (identifier, value);
    }

    public int getInt (String identifier) {
        return map.get (identifier);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had a Map you could do that or if you used reflection. The best way is to just create a getter and setter pair per instance variable:

```
private int age;

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
```

---

If you had a map like the following, you could achieve this:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

public void setInt(String property, int value) {
    properties.put(property, value);
}

public int getInt(String property) {
    return (int) properties.get(property);
}

// Usage
setInt("age", 25);
int age = getInt("age");
```